# Can I run a program that uses one git branch and work on another branch at the same time?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

If I have two branches, `master` and `new-feature`, can I run a program that uses `master` then switch to `new-feature` without effecting the original program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least these two possibilities to consider :

1) Clone your repo. Work on one repo, let the other one run your program. It seems the most straightforward way to go from what you describe.

2) Maybe look at [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

It allows you to check out multiple branches at once, in separate directories.

Your program could run on a version from branch A, while you work on branch B checked out on your second worktree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git checkout new-feature` to switch to the code for the feature. 
This way, you can work on it as you like, without effecting the live site at `master`.